# Issue loading content with jQuery UI Tabs with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have my jQuery UI Tabs working right now but need help implementing the Ajax side. What I need help with is getting `#tab-2` to show information (`@user.messages`) from the `MessagesController` in a layout that exists as a partial in the `MessagesController`.

**My `application.js`:**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        ajaxOptions: {
            error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
                $( anchor.hash ).html(
                    "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                    "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**My profile `show.html.erb`:**

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul id="infoContainer">
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">About</a></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Messages", "messages/profile_messages", :remote => true %></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
  </div><!-- end profile-about -->
</div>
```

**My `_profile_messages` partial in MessagesController:**

```
<div id="tabs-2">
    <% for 'message' in @user.messages %>
        <div class="message">
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**Here is the HTML output of the jQuery UI Tabs:**

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul id="infoContainer">
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="messages/profile_messages" data-remote="true">Messages</a></li>
  </ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
```

**Here are the tabs as seen in Firebug:**

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <ul id="infoContainer" class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#tabs-1">About</a></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#ui-tabs-1" data-remote="true">Messages</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
  </div>
</div>
```

The fact that Firebug shows the second link as #ui-tabs-1 seems odd to me. Then when I click the "Messages" link to load the @user.messages, Firebug shows an error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - :3000/profiles/messages/profile_messages`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the combined efforts of folks here on SO I was able to get this to work. Check out these questions for more code:

[Exclude application layout in Rails 3 div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697317/exclude-application-layout-in-rails-3-div)

[Rails 3 jQuery UI Tabs issue loading with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693012/rails-3-jquery-ui-tabs-issue-loading-with-ajax/7698207#comment9363399_7698207)